# How to interrogate GUI controls in a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, debugging

Still setting my first steps in WPF, this time I'm dealing with this "simple" situation:

```
dt_Proposal.Rows[0].ItemArray[i] = highest_val + min_val;
```

This piece of code has been run for every value of `i` (also for value 2), so I expect to see something on the place of the red rounded rectangle:

[image]

However I don't see any value there.

I decided to pauze my application (Visual Studio "Debug" menu, "Break All" menu item), and then I thought of having a look at the controls of my form, but how?

Visual Studio's "Locals" window contains `this`, which is mentioned being a `<Application_Name>.MainWindow`, but I can't look deeper.
When adding `this` to the "Watchlist", `this` seems not even to be accessible.

So this becomes a very general question: I am working on the GUI of a WPF application, and I would like to see the properties/fields of the controls/GUI components of my main form, and I would like to do this while my application is waiting on any kind of user input (typical "wait state" for a GUI application).
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF you can see Visual Tree (even without pausing the app at all!), you enter this like shown in below picture:

[image]

By the way, value `hello world` was set programatically:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txtInfo.Text = "hello world";
}
```

Once in Visual Tree, you can right click control and show its properties:
[image]

And there you can see values of properties set:
[image]